# Android Studio unable to find preview channel under SDK manager from Android studio upgrade from 1.2 to 1.3

Tags: android

My project was using build tool 23 rc3, and I have upgraded my Android Studio to 1.3.  After that, my project throws me error about not finding 23.0.0 rc3 in the build tool. "Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc3
Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc3 and sync project"
Android Studio unable to find preview channel under SDK manager from Android studio upgrade from 1.2 to 1.3

Comment: I think because of stable version of 23

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat throws

```
"Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc3 Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc3 and sync project"
```

**FYI** `23.0.0 rc3 Is not stable Use 23 instead rc3` .

Use `Stable version instead Beta` . Then `Sync with gradle & Restart` .I hope it will helps you .

Comment: but my team uses rc3, so i need to solve this problem. how can i download rc3 again?

Comment: You can download latest stable version 1.3.2 . set buildtoolversion 23 . I used and faced same problem. Then I switched to this.

Comment: But i need to use 23.0.0 rc3 instead of 23 though.

Answer (score 0):

The Preview Channel is available into help option in android studio :

checkout below screenshot :

[image]

Click on Updates link to get second window in screenshot .